# How can I update the geolocation when creating a .las file using pylas?

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, lidar, las

pylas community! I am relatively new to pylas but I have experience working with web-based graphics/geospatial engines and a variety of 3D data types.

In a project that I am currently working on, I am reading in data from the Mapillary API and exporting it as a .las file. I am able to do this successfully and even got some [nice results](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=lVNdb9owFP0rFg9TkCoH6IfWllZDULEgAv1Iu4Hy4iYXcHHszHaAMPW/z05CW7a12p6cXJ9z77nnXrsu6kvCNeqColkyuEMkikAppAXKRSYRFRwRpUCrkJcY7AmOY5iRjOlOAQ7EEji6QGEN8sHisR/RMR1491uvOaKe8vjtcdT1Trxl+v2hOzjFBvQj7i8NyMtH/ft8HERNP280/GDZGga3yTS40pPkfjOljXz87WYzDeYN/2mUTJ58OuwO0qlJNurdNP3tRHkJW8Tm3w8mm1Gvc+z3orX/tYHp7Y3XbV0/6IfW0+HnI08sTpMxbYneveAbxXw66beu+vOb+fAorJ2HPOQrItGKwhqk6YTDunIEPxQxJ6xFxX9XcE0oBxnWDtDPkCOkQUoTuZZiRWOQZ2/J5RHsI5yChlAm2Rl69fQWlDE8AjyTIulYy73YadYPLPjZHs91I7SUiFUEHPCciUcws0j1IgClO3NTRemqnGlDywxemtOUgUlqwns5UkkTqukKFCZx7NhqfzRw2AtK8v9IPzk8Pjo93ukPeb1QUqnAEkicG0cSqsAisF4Ad2YZj7RdOaeOqlKV2K0QSSCcim5z2ctdtlRQrrtMZPHdgsSUzzHRGnhGimQvRnxMSciGJlnS2WOe4Eah21JdF3XSlOXIaEXVC0BK5wwQnSGqEWyosg+l0G0sh42WRNn6VdHiJeEyXOkxTKf8QjtHTWqzYbFT4uro06cPAdgo/SfQ7tXeWcn1Ev7i86szZUcX761BwX43a9XV827qZrLC2CXXZs5vxmtWVMiX2pHgSjDATMyrm/OSb47aQa1dKLq0oS80SYXUdgEdjF0NScqIBuU+ZtHSaI+UsqS2u6O0Y7pCNL74y/tFETPzMDezjLE7uoWwdtl2DX6PxkSxHeMVSEZyA7Ey2ovm5bC8wBi3XfNri/7O1UKwRyLf5P0F).

However, I am struggling to add a geolocation to the data that I export. The current `.las` file that I am creating does not have a geolocation. Thus, I am updating the location manually to get the desired result. What part of the pylas API should I be using to accomplish this? Thank you!

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
# LAS point format 2 supports color
header = laspy.header.Header(point_format=2)
with laspy.file.File(filename, mode="w", header=header) as lasfile:
    # lasfile.header.offset = header.offset
    lasfile.header.scale = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
    # updating coordinates
    lasfile.x = np.array(x)
    lasfile.y = np.array(y)
    lasfile.z = np.array(z)
    # updating RGB
    lasfile.red = r
    lasfile.green = g
    lasfile.blue = b
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? lol

Comment: Hi @iRunner. Sadly, I have not found a solution. I currently do not have the bandwidth to work on this project so I have just put this issue on hold.